# Searching for duplicate rows in one column, how to exclude if duplicated in another?

Tags: mysql

I am searching for duplicate addresses however I have some results with duplicate results in "Completed". How can I exclude those results from being shown? Here is my current query

```
SELECT WorkOrder, list.Address, list.Completed
FROM list
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT list.Address
    FROM list
    WHERE list.Reference = 0
    GROUP BY Address
    Having COUNT(WorkOrder) = 2
    )
    temp ON list.Address = temp.Address
WHERE list.Address != ""
ORDER BY list.Address ASC, list.Completed ASC
```

Example Output:

```
WorkOrder | Address | Completed
41471286 | 127 LONG LN | 1
65381835 | 127 LONG LN | 1
39796565 | 13516 MOORING DR | 0
68128218 | 13516 MOORING DR | 1
39796559 | 13520 MOORING DR | 0
68004427 | 13520 MOORING DR | 1
```

I need the first two results to not appear in my search as both have Completed marked with a 1.

Comment: Please add DDLs, SQLFiddle for data that you have so people can give better answer.

Comment: How does the `Reference = 0` factor into this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT WorkOrder, Address, MIN(Completed) FROM list GROUP BY WorkOrder, Address
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach does not look far off.  In my query below, I group by *both* the `Address` and `Completed` columns, using the following criteria for whether an address/completed pair will be retained:

```
HAVING SUM(Completed) < 2
```

This condition will remove your duplicates where both records have been marked as complete, but will retain everything else.

```
SELECT t1.WorkOrder,
       t1.Address,
       t1.Completed
FROM list t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Address, Completed
    FROM list
    WHERE Reference = 0             -- don't know what this is for, as it does not appear
    GROUP BY Address, Completed     -- in your sample data
    HAVING SUM(Completed) < 2       -- retain if completed is not marked twice or more
) t2
    ON t1.Address = t2.Address AND
       t1.Completed = t2.Completed
WHERE t1.Address != ""
ORDER BY t1.Address,
         t1.Completed
```